# Why only one result in loop scrapy

Tags: python, loops, scrapy

I'm trying to use *scrapy* to crawl some page with a lot of links inside, but my existing code so far only show the contents of the first link.

What mistake have I made?

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Proje.items import ProjeItem

class ProjeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "someweb"
    allowed_domains = ["someweb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://someweb.com/indeks/"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@id="indeks-container"]'):
        for tete in sel.xpath('//linkkk').re('//linkkk.*?(?=")'):
           links = 'http:'+str(tete)
           req = Request(links,callback=self.kontene)
           return req

def kontene(self, response):
    for mbuh in response.xpath('//head'):
        Item = ProjeItem()
        Item['title'] = mbuh.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        yield Item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the scrapy docs, [`parse` needs to return an interable](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse) of `Request`, i.e. a list or a generator. Just change `return` to `yield` and it should work as expected:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@id="indeks-container"]'):
        for tete in sel.xpath('//linkkk').re('//linkkk.*?(?=")'):
           links = 'http:'+str(tete)
           req = Request(links,callback=self.kontene)
           yield req
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a `return` statement within your `for` loop. In Python, a `return` will return out of the function, giving you only the first links worth of content. Instead, consider adding `req` to a list of returned objects.

```
def parse(self, response):
    req_list = []
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@id="indeks-container"]'):
        for tete in sel.xpath('//linkkk').re('//linkkk.*?(?=")'):
           links = 'http:'+str(tete)
           req = Request(links,callback=self.kontene)
           req_list += req
    return req_list
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm stil trying to use your suggestion but i still got Request object is not iterable.. i have tried to change the line but it still error

Comment: @insecte Is there more than the code shown? This probably means you are trying to loop over the req object itself somewhere.

Comment: i have edited my question with my whole code.. thank you

Comment: actually you may just `yield req` instead of return and it should work fine. no need to build a list in memory

Comment: @miraculixx i tried that, and its only give me a result from first link from the    links

Comment: if you tried `yield` and still only get one link then your xpath query likely produces just one link. have you tried [using the parse command](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#parse-command) to see what your parse method actually does?

Comment: @miraculixx thank you so much, it's worked now.. i have issues with indented blocks with the `yield`

Comment: @miraculixx So if I'm reading this correctly, my solution is totally wrong and I should probably remove it?

Comment: @JennerFelton from my POV your solution should work too, is just uses more memory to build `req_list`, compared the using a `yield` statement. Also scrapy may be able to process yield'ed values sooner than if it has to wait for he whole list, improving overall crawling performance. But that's a shot in the dark, YMMV.